# Getting the value from specific tag of a XML file in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm starting working with XML files and I know little about it.

What I need is read the value from a certain tag of a XML file

```
<Tag>
<Name>PBAS</Name>
<ID>1</ID>
<Description>Array of sequence characters as edited by user</Description>
<Type>char</Type>
<Elements>163</Elements>
<Size>163</Size>
    <Value>TCCGAACAAGCGGCGAGTGCTGGGCGAGTGGCCGCGGGGCTGTGGTCCTGTGCACGGTGATCGCAAGGGCCCCCGGGGCTTGCTGGTCTTCCCTAACGGTTCGTGGAACCCCCGAAGCTGGGGGCTGGCCAGGGGCTTAAGGAACCCTTCCTAAATTAACTAC</Value>
</Tag>
```

I need, in the example above, getting the string between the "Value"(the string TCCGA...) of the tag named "PBAS" with "ID 1".

But I need this value just from the tag named PBAS with "ID1", since the XML document has other "values" from other tags named differently.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What C# code do you use?

Comment: I don't know how to do this exactly :(
I'm opening the xml file from an openFileDialog and then I don't know how to proceed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var yourval = XDocument.Load(filename)
                .XPathSelectElement("//Tag[Name='PBAS' and ID='1']")
                .Element("Value")
                .Value;
```

or

```
var yourval = (string)XDocument.Load(filename)
                      .XPathSelectElement("//Tag[Name='PBAS' and ID='1']/Value");
```

or (using only Linq)

```
var yourval = XDocument.Load(filename)
              .Descendants("Tag")
              .Where(t => (string)t.Element("Name") == "PBAS")
              .Where(t => (string)t.Element("ID") == "1")
              .First()
              .Element("Value")
              .Value;
```

PS: Necessary namespaces: `System.Xml`, `System.Xml.XPath`, and `System.Xml.Linq` . Also Read about [Linq2Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx) and [Xpath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675178.aspx)

Comment: It has worked fine!
Thanks a lot, EZI!

Answer (score 1):

The technology to select nodes from XML is called XPath. Basically you create a path of element names separated by `/` like

```
/Tag/Value
```

To specify conditions, put them in square brackets at the place from where you want to start the condition:

```
/Tag[./Name/text()="PBAS"][./ID/text()="1"]/Value
```

Above XPath is good for demonstration purposes, since it explains how it works. In practice, this would be simplified to

```
/Tag[Name="PBAS"][ID="1"]/Value
```

Code:

```
using System.Xml;

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/Tag[./Name/text()=\"PBAS\"][./ID/text()=\"1\"]/Value");
foreach (XmlElement node in nodes)
{                
    Console.WriteLine(node.InnerText);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Use `doc.Load(filename)` if you have a file name

Comment: Plus one for being the only answer to offer hints and tips rather than a full hardcoded solution. OP can catch his own fish now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code:

```
string xmlFile = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\Work_Time_Calculator\10-07-2013.xml");
                XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlFile);
                XmlNodeList xnList = xmldoc.SelectNodes("/Tag");
                string Value ="";
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  string ID = xn["ID"].InnerText;
  if(ID =="1")
  {
  value = xn["Value"].InnerText;
  }
}
```

Comment: Assuming that you put the contents of the xml file in the file with the specified path : D:\Work_Time_Calculator\10-07-2013.xml